# Why am I getting unrecognized tag errors in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

So I'm trying to complete a react web tutorial to learn how to make Android and iOS apps and I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=469&v=_CBYbEGvxYY
But when I try to run a simple page to test some hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { TextComponent } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const[count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <view>
      <text>{count}</text>
      <button title="Increment" onKeyPress={()=> setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </view>
  );
}
  
export default App;
```

I'm getting the following console errors:

> Warning: The tag `<text>` is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

And the program doesn't increment the the count at all. Also I tried changing the tag name to have a capital like the error suggests but that doesn't work because then the tag isn't recognized. Can someone please help me?
Note: I'm confused as to why I'm getting these errors now because before when I just had a simple view with text in it, the program worked properly but now I'm getting these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tag called `<text>` in HTML. In the video, they imported:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
```

So you need to make sure you're importing and using the correct components. They are CaSe SeNsItIvE:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const[count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{count}</Text>
      <button title="Increment" onKeyPress={()=> setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the display of it but it's still not incrementing. Do you have any idea why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Because you're probably looking for `onclick` vs `onkeypress`

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it! I was just following the video so I'm not sure why it works for them with onkeypress